# How to fix error in installing npm package (Failed at the iltorb@1.3.10 install script)?

Tags: node.js, npm, angular7, npm-install

I'm setting up a npm package for a project in which there ngx-loader is going to be used. Here is the error while installing npm package.

```
prebuild-install WARN install No prebuilt binaries found (target=11.14.0 runtime=node arch=x64 platform=linux)
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: not found: make
gyp ERR! stack     at getNotFoundError (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:13:12)
gyp ERR! stack     at F (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:68:19)
gyp ERR! stack     at E (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:80:29)
gyp ERR! stack     at /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:89:16
gyp ERR! stack     at /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/isexe/index.js:42:5
gyp ERR! stack     at /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/isexe/mode.js:8:5
gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:158:21)
gyp ERR! System Linux 4.18.0-18-generic
gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /media/shubham/A/Angular/ngx-loading-bar-master/node_modules/iltorb
gyp ERR! node -v v11.14.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! iltorb@1.3.10 install: `detect-libc prebuild-install || node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the iltorb@1.3.10 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

I expect npm package to be installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like this is the problem: this is from their [npm page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-gyp)

> You will also need to install
> On Unix
> `python` (v2.7 recommended, v3.x.x is not supported) 
> `make` A proper C/C++ compiler toolchain, like GCC

Comment: I'm on Catalina, had the same problem, solved by `node-gyp` instructions (https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/blob/master/macOS_Catalina.md) — you need to log in to Apple Developers and download `Command Line Tools 11.3.1` (or newer) — after that, both `node-gyp` tests passed